# Error when adding trustpilot extension

Tags: magento2, error, composer

Whenever I add the trustpilot extension using composer require it succeeds but afterwards when I try to use any `php bin/magento` command it returns it with this error:

> Warning: require(/home/nolimi2q/public_html/vendor/composer/../symfony/polyfill-mbstring/bootstrap.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/nolimi2q/public_html/vendor/composer/autoload_real.php on line 70
>
> Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required '/home/nolimi2q/public_html/vendor/composer/../symfony/polyfill-mbstring/bootstrap.php' (include_path='/home/nolimi2q/public_html/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library:.:/opt/alt/php72/usr/share/pear') in /home/nolimi2q/public_html/vendor/composer/autoload_real.php on line 70

Answer (score 1):

Please remove `generated` and all folders in `var` folder from the root directory.
And then please run the all commands.

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade

php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f

php bin/magento indexer:reindex

php bin/magento cache:flush

php bin/magento cache:clean
```

This will work your extension fine.

Thanks

Comment: The error has changed from that to: Warning: require(/home/nolimi2q/public_html/vendor/composer/../../registration.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/nolimi2q/public_html/vendor/composer/autoload_real.php online 70

Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required '/home/nolimi2q/public_html/vendor/composer/../../registration.php' (include_path='/home/nolimi2q/public_html/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library:.:/opt/alt/php72/usr/share/pear') in /home/nolimi2q/public_html/vendor/composer/autoload_real.php on line 70

Comment: Extension have to add composer please check the composer command and run and after that it will work.

Comment: What do you mean by check the composer command? I've tried multiple composer commands but none worked. The error stays like that.

Comment: No particular extension have composer command.

Comment: It happens when i install any extension for that mattter. Is it not a file missing in vendorcomposer? or a path missing in the autoload_real.php?